# Java get component dimension in constructor

Tags: java, panel

I have a Panel which needs to know its size inside the constructor:

```
class Panneau extends JPanel {
    public Panneau() {
        super();
        new Map(getSize());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the size doesn’t seem to have been initialized yet and `getSize()` returns a `Dimension` with 0 for height and width. How to get the future `Dimension` notwithstanding?

Comment: Um is `Panneau` supposed to inherit from `Panel`?  Right now it doesn't.  So `super();` would just be the `Object` class constructor.

Comment: Right, I forgot the `extends JPanel` in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with the size of a component, you need to do so when the component is actually in use in a well-formed user interface.

One of the ways to do that, is to add a `ComponentListener` to the code and implement the `componentResized` method, which will be called whenever the component's size changes. There you can work with the latest accurate value for the component's size by using `getSize()`.